# focal-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I'm not being able to update with `apt update` command. I'm getting an error which says:

```
Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as
repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease'
doesn't support architecture '1386'
```

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: The first thing you're going to want to do is to fix that `1386` (one-386) issue, as that's not an architecture ⇢ `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386`

Answer (score 0):

you should replace `1386` to `i386`, it's an I, not an 1.