# Trouble updating and downloading anything

Tags: apt, updates

I recently just fixed a libssl1.1:amd64 package error that was preventing me from downloading anything. I used this source: [focal-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301000/focal-backports-inrelease-doesnt-support-architecture-1386). I used the command line mentioned; `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Now I can start to download, but once finished I'm told to update. I tried `apt update` and `sudo apt-get update`, both with these results:

```
apt update 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I've tried removing the lock file, hasn't worked.

sudo apt update (I've removed my IP address):

```
sudo apt update 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease          
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease [115 kB]    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease           
Get:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease [101 kB]  
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease              
  Connection timed out [IP: ]
Fetched 216 kB in 58s (3.694 B/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
133 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy-security/InRelease  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm not exactly sure what wrong here, but I'm certain there wasn't an update.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The specific error your output is showing is `13: Permission denied`...usually because the user ran `apt update` instead of `sudo apt update`. If you did really run `sudo apt update`, then show us *that* output in your question.

Comment: I've added the output. The problem seems to be the 1386 architecture.

Comment: Note that you no longer have the original lockfile/permission issues, so that issue is solved. Your current problems seem unrelated to your original question. Looks like you were trying to add the 'i386' architecture and made a typo. Do you recall what you were doing that caused you to try to add that architecture?

Comment: Yes I was fixing the libssl1.1:amd64 package error 1 earlier today. I copied and pasted the command from what I thought was a credible source. It fixed the problem nonetheless.

Comment: Are you going to post those commands and source in your question? Or do you already know how to fix it?

Comment: No I don't know how to fix it. Although I did post the source and command I used.

Comment: You wrote that you used the command `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386` which is incorrect for the problem that you have. You should have used `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386`. See the difference?

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. It worked.